# AlertDialog window size is large

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using simple Alertdialog to show a message that location Coordinates saved successfully. But Alertdialog window is large compared to Alertdialog window. I tried with both android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog and android.app.AlertDialog.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Location Coordinates saved successfully");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: size for what? width?

Comment: is it me, or this sentence is really obfuscating? *But Alertdialog window is large compared to Alertdialog window.*

Comment: Yes. Please post code for both. Not just for one. Which one?

Comment: width and height are double as compared to normal alertdialog

Answer (score 2):

You can set alertdialog size by

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

params.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
params.width = 200;
params.height = 400;

params.x=100;
params.y=100;

alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**add alert Dialog Box like this**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,
     You wanted to make decision");
  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", 
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked yes 
           button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  });

  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();
     }
  });

  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
  }
```

**OR**

**another way you can give the height and width**

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   builder.setView(layout);
   builder.setTitle("Title");
   alertDialog = builder.create();
   alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.
```

pls try it i hope it helps you